# Unable to load module that uses a named define call

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using RequireJS & its working fine for some modules.  Recently, I added two test modules (code for the modules seems to be fine).  I am importing them in my main (javascript) file and I can see that the file get imported in the browser.  However, I see the following error message and I cannot troubleshoot properly what might be causing this issue. Any suggestions to fix or troubleshoot this will be greatly appreciated.

**Error Message in browser**

```
Error: No define call for urlCore/urlTest http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine


...{c=c[b]});return c}function C(b,c,d,g){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/er...
```

**module to be imported:**

```
define("urlTest", [], function() {  //no dependencies on other modules
    'use strict';
    var urlTest = function() {   
           this.getTestURL = function(url, urlChk) { 
               if (typeof url === 'undefined' || typeof urlChk === 'undefined' ||
                       url === '' || urlChk === '') {  //we can check length instead as well || removing typeof does not solve the issue
                      throw new Error("urlCommon - url or urlChk values are invalid:" + url + "|" + urlChk);  
                   }
                if (url !== null && url.length > 0 && urlChk === "Y") {
                    return url;
                } 
                }; //end of getTestURL
                urlTest.version = '0.0.1';
    };
    return urlTest; 
});
```

I tried this but it does not work either:

```
/*
    define("urlTest", [], function() {  //no dependencies on other modules
        'use strict';
    return {
        getTestURL : function(url, urlChk) { 
            if (url !== null && url.length > 0 && urlChk === "Y") {
                return url;
            } 
        }
    } //end return
});  //end test module

*/
```

**Main.js paths:**

```
paths: {
    //"jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min"
        'validateTest': 'validation/validateTest',  //works
        'normalizedXHR': 'xhr/normalizedXHR',  //works
    'urlTest': 'urlCore/urlTest',  //does not work
    'jsonTest': 'json/jsonTest'   //does not work
}
```

**Update:**
I am using the urlTest from this module:

```
define('testResponse', ['./urlCore/urlTest', './json/jsonTest'], function(urlTest, jsonTest) {  
    'use strict';
```

**Another Update**
When I set **enforceDefine** to true with **waitSeconds** to a value greater than 0, I receive the following error (even though I see the JS file being loaded in the browser):

```
Error: Load timeout for modules: urlCore/urlTest
```

This urlTest is a dependency in a module (which sits in another directory).  When I try the following, the dependencies do not load up in the browser:

```
define('testResponse', ['../urlCore/urlTest'], function(urlTest) {
```

When I try the following, the file appears to load in the browser window but I get the requirejs error stating a load timeout for module error.

```
 define('testResponse', ['./urlCore/urlTest'], function(urlTest) {
```

**File structure:**

```
javascripts
javascripts/main.js
javascripts/abc/testResponse.js
javascripts/urlCore/urlTest.js
```

**Another Update**
I am able to call other modules residing in a separate directory.  The issue comes forward when one of the modules in those directories e.g. abc/testResponse has a dependency on urlCore/urlTest.  This appears to cause the issue for me.  Should I be specifying the config part in this module as well in addition to the main.js (I'm not doing that right now).

```
define('testResponse', ['./urlCore/urlTest'], function(urlTest) {
```

When I try the **../urlCore/urlTest**, the file does not event load up.

Comment: Probably posted too soon - I removed "enforceDefine: true" (or just make it false) and the error went away.  I am still not sure why enforceDefine is not causing a problem with other modules.

Comment: Is there *anywhere* in your code where a `define` or `require` call has a dependency named `urlCore/urlTest` (rather than `urlTest`)? Note that removing `enforceDefine: true` is essentially telling RequireJS to not report certain errors. (There are probably some use-case scenarios where not having `enforceDefine: true` is correct but I've not encountered them.) So it is not fixing the problem but masking it.

Comment: yes, there is a separate module that has a dependency on urlCore/urlTest.  I am updating the post with the define statement for that module.

Comment: is it the blank array that is it expecting a url in? try removing `[]`.  I won't post this as an answer because I don't know if it will actually work

Comment: @Funkodebat I am assuming you are talking about the blank array in the urlTest module.  If so, that's for declaring dependencies for urlTest and currently, there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by what you are showing in the question, `urlTest` is loaded with the path `urlCore/urlTest` and at this path there is a file which contains this:

```
define("urlTest", [], function() {
```

This works, so long as what RequireJS is loading a module named `urlTest`. No problem there. However, if you require any other module name that ultimately resolves to the path `urlCore/urlTest`, then you are in trouble, because the module name will not correspond to the name that you have in your `define` call. Or to put it differently, for your module to load when required under the name `urlCore/urlTest`, the `define` call in the module's file would have to say:

```
define("urlCore/urlTest", [], function() {
```

The easy fix for this is to not assign names to modules in your `define` calls. Just put the dependencies and the callback and leave the name out.

Even if you use `define` without specifying a module name, you *still* have to be careful not to end up loading the *same* module under *two* different names, because if you do, you will get a timeout when you try loading with the 2nd name. In the code you show in the question, I'd recommend using `urlTest` everywhere or using relative paths everywhere to load this module but don't mix the two.

Comment: thanks for sharing - I tried it but that did not work for me.  I'm reasonably sure I'm making a mistake somewhere but can't figure out what as of now.  This is what I tried in the define call "(define(function() {"  (without the inverted commas) but this did not work

Comment: also, I mistyped earlier - the urlTest is in the urlCore directory (only js file with that name)

Comment: I'm updating the post - it would be life saver if you had an idea of what's causing the issue.

Comment: I removed the names as well as the empty dependency brackets - if it was not needed, I removed it as opposed to keeping it empty.  That seems to have taken care of this issue.  Much appreciated!